# How to display data from Excel file in a Webpart

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, javascript, html

I want to create a website on sharepoint 2010 which displays data from an Excel file in a Web part. Unfortunately, Excel Services is not available. Therefore, Excel REST cannot be used and due to security restrictions the access via `ActiveXObject()` in JavaScript is also not possible.

Do you know another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to read and parse your Excel files (check [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) for XSLX files and [js-xls](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls) for XLS files, and there are some other librairies on the Web). Of course these files must be on the same domaine (so if you work on http://my.website.com then the Excel files must be also located under http://my.website.com).

Once you read/parse them, you can create an HTML version of the content (use the methods provided by js-xls to get the content to an array for example) and print it into the page. You can even use some advanced library like [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) to reproduce the Excel-like behavior for your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Without Excel Services, You cannot have anything to render the Excel file as HTML.

You could open the Excel file, Save As "Web Page" and upload the HTML file. This can then be displayed in a Page Viewer Web Part.

I dont how much access you have to server side coding.You can use SPFile class to read excel workbook from library then select table range to display in your webpart. Here is some good ref links for you:

http://alancejacob.blogspot.in/2012/06/read-data-from-excel-file-and-insert-in.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496608/read-excel-file-stored-in-sharepoint-document-library